# Configure SpringBoot Kafka streams unit tests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a SpringBoot Kafka streams maven app. I use a spring-boot-starter-parent 2.4.4 for my springboot dependencies and kafka-streams 2.7.0.

I am stuck at running tests with

`java.lang.NullPointerException`
when trying to load my application configuration from either
resources/application.yml or test/resources/application-test.resources or test/resources/application.yml

I have a Config class with this annotations and getters and setters for fields, which are defined with same name as in the application.yml

```java
package com.acme.rtc.configuration;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "topics")
@Component
@Configuration
public class ConfigProps {

    private String MATRIXX_ADJ_EVENT_TOPIC;

    private String OUTPUT_MNVO_KGN_ADJ_EVENT_TOPIC;

    private String OUTPUT_MNVO_LEB_ADJ_EVENT_TOPIC;

    private String EVENTS_NO_MVNO;


    public void setMATRIXX_ADJ_EVENT_TOPIC(String MATRIXX_ADJ_EVENT_TOPIC) {
        this.MATRIXX_ADJ_EVENT_TOPIC = MATRIXX_ADJ_EVENT_TOPIC;
    }

    public void setOUTPUT_MNVO_KGN_ADJ_EVENT_TOPIC(String OUTPUT_MNVO_KGN_ADJ_EVENT_TOPIC) {
        this.OUTPUT_MNVO_KGN_ADJ_EVENT_TOPIC = OUTPUT_MNVO_KGN_ADJ_EVENT_TOPIC;
    }

    public void setOUTPUT_MNVO_LEB_ADJ_EVENT_TOPIC(String OUTPUT_MNVO_LEB_ADJ_EVENT_TOPIC) {
        this.OUTPUT_MNVO_LEB_ADJ_EVENT_TOPIC = OUTPUT_MNVO_LEB_ADJ_EVENT_TOPIC;
    }

    public String getEVENTS_NO_MVNO() {
        return EVENTS_NO_MVNO;
    }

    public void setEVENTS_NO_MVNO(String EVENTS_NO_MVNO) {
        this.EVENTS_NO_MVNO = EVENTS_NO_MVNO;
    }

    public String getMATRIXX_ADJ_EVENT_TOPIC() {
        return MATRIXX_ADJ_EVENT_TOPIC;
    }

    public String getOUTPUT_MNVO_KGN_ADJ_EVENT_TOPIC() {
        return OUTPUT_MNVO_KGN_ADJ_EVENT_TOPIC;
    }

    public String getOUTPUT_MNVO_LEB_ADJ_EVENT_TOPIC() {
        return OUTPUT_MNVO_LEB_ADJ_EVENT_TOPIC;
    }

}
```

I am doing @Autowire of this class in my test and app class,

```java
@Autowired
ConfigProps cp;
```

and trying to access fields using `cp.getBootstrapServerHost()` but this resolves to a NullPointer in my test class. But resolves properly in my application class...

My test class looks like this

```java
package distinct;

import com.acme.rtc.configuration.ConfigProps;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.*;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaStreamsConfiguration;
import com.acme.rtc.configuration.KafkaConfiguration;
import com.acme.rtc.configuration.TopologyConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringJUnitConfig;

import java.util.List;

import static java.util.Collections.singletonList;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TopologyConfiguration.class)
@SpringJUnitConfig
public class TestWithTopologyTestDriver {
    private TestInputTopic<String, String> inputTopicWrong;
    private TestOutputTopic<String, String> outputTopicWrong;

    private TestInputTopic<String, String> inputTopicRight;
    private TestOutputTopic<String, String> outputTopicRight;
    private TopologyTestDriver topologyTestDriver;

    @Autowired
    ConfigProps configProps;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        KafkaProperties properties = new KafkaProperties();
        properties.setBootstrapServers(singletonList("localhost:9092"));
        KafkaStreamsConfiguration config = new KafkaConfiguration(properties).getStreamsConfig();
        StreamsBuilder sb = new StreamsBuilder();
        Topology topology = new TopologyConfiguration().createTopology(sb);
        topologyTestDriver = new TopologyTestDriver(topology, config.asProperties());
        inputTopicWrong =
                topologyTestDriver.createInputTopic(configProps.getMATRIXX_ADJ_EVENT_TOPIC(), new StringSerializer(),
                        new StringSerializer());
        outputTopicWrong =
                topologyTestDriver.createOutputTopic(configProps.getOUTPUT_MNVO_KGN_ADJ_EVENT_TOPIC(), new StringDeserializer(),
                        new StringDeserializer());

        inputTopicRight =
                topologyTestDriver.createInputTopic(configProps.getMATRIXX_ADJ_EVENT_TOPIC(), new StringSerializer(),
                        new StringSerializer());
        outputTopicRight =
                topologyTestDriver.createOutputTopic(configProps.getOUTPUT_MNVO_LEB_ADJ_EVENT_TOPIC(), new StringDeserializer(),
                        new StringDeserializer());
    }

    @AfterEach
    public void tearDown() {
        topologyTestDriver.close();
    }
@Test
    void wrongDistinctTopology() {
        testTopology(inputTopicWrong, outputTopicWrong);
    }}
```

where `TopologyConfiguration` is my application and that has this signature

```java
package com.acme.rtc.configuration;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.NewTopic;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serde;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsBuilder;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.Topology;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.*;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.Acknowledgment;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "topics")
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class TopologyConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    @Autowired
    ConfigProps configProps;

    private void acmeStreamsTopoloy(StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder) {

        Deserializer<JsonNode> jsonDeserializer = new JsonDeserializer();
        Serializer<JsonNode> jsonSerializer = new JsonSerializer();
        Serde<JsonNode> jsonSerde = Serdes.serdeFrom(jsonSerializer, jsonDeserializer);
        System.out.println("ConfigProps.getMattrix: "+configProps.getMATRIXX_ADJ_EVENT_TOPIC());


        KStream<String, String> inputStream =
                streamsBuilder.stream(configProps.getMATRIXX_ADJ_EVENT_TOPIC(), Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()));
        KStream<String, String>[] branches = inputStream.branch(
                (key, value)-> value.contains("KGN"),
                (key, value)-> value.contains("LEB"),
                (key, value)->true);

        branches[0].to(configProps.getOUTPUT_MNVO_KGN_ADJ_EVENT_TOPIC());
        branches[1].to(configProps.getOUTPUT_MNVO_LEB_ADJ_EVENT_TOPIC());
        branches[2].to(configProps.getEVENTS_NO_MVNO());

    }


    @Bean
    public Topology createTopology(StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder) {
        acmeStreamsTopoloy(streamsBuilder);
        return streamsBuilder.build();
    }


}
```

My KafkaConfiguration class

```java
package com.acme.rtc.configuration;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.LogAndContinueExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaStreamsDefaultConfiguration;
import org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaStreamsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.Acknowledgment;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class KafkaConfiguration {

    public static final String APP_ID = "acme-stream-rtc";
    private final KafkaProperties kafkaProperties;


    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = KafkaStreamsDefaultConfiguration.DEFAULT_STREAMS_CONFIG_BEAN_NAME)
    public KafkaStreamsConfiguration getStreamsConfig() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, APP_ID);
        props.put(StreamsConfig.NUM_STREAM_THREADS_CONFIG, 2);
        props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaProperties.getBootstrapServers());
        props.put(JsonSerializer.ADD_TYPE_INFO_HEADERS,false);
        KafkaStreamsConfiguration streamsConfig = new KafkaStreamsConfiguration(props);
        return streamsConfig;
    }


}
```

My application.yml has the right syntax etc.

```yaml
spring:
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
  json:
    value:
      default:
        type: true
kafka:
  streams:
    properties:
      default:
        value:
          serde: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerde
      admin:
    security:
      protocol: SSL
    ssl:
      trust-store-location: ${TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION}
      trust-store-password: ${TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD}
      key-store-location: ${KEYSTORE_LOCATION}
      key-store-password: ${KEYSTORE_PASSWORD}
      key-password: ${KEY_PASSWORD}


topics:
  MATRIXX_ADJ_EVENT_TOPIC: input-matrixx-adj-event
  OUTPUT_MNVO_KGN_ADJ_EVENT_TOPIC: output-KGN-adj-event
  OUTPUT_MNVO_LEB_ADJ_EVENT_TOPIC: output-LEB-adj-event
  EVENTS_NO_MVNO: events-no-mvno-spec
```

My main class

```java
package com.acme.rtc;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.EnableKafkaStreams;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableKafkaStreams
public class StreamProcessing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(StreamProcessing.class, args);
    }

}
```

I am not sure if I am missing any context when Autowiring my ConfigProps class or if I need further annotations on my test class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For JUnit4 you need `@Runwith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` alongside the `@ContextConfiguration`.

For JUnit5, use `@SpringJUnitConfig`.

For proper loading of properties, though, you need `@SpringBootTest`.

Boot 2.4 uses JUnit5.

And you should not have `@ConfigurationProperties` on the test.

**EDIT**

I just tested it with no problems.

```java
@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean
    String str() {
        return "str";
    }

}


@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "foo")
@Component
public class MyProps {

    String bar;

    public String getBar() {
        return this.bar;
    }

    public void setBar(String bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyProps [bar=" + this.bar + "]";
    }

}

@SpringBootApplication
public class So67078244Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So67078244Application.class, args);
    }

}

@SpringBootTest
class So67078244ApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    MyProps props;

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
        System.out.println(this.props);
    }

}
```

```
foo.bar=baz
```

```
MyProps [bar=baz]
```

Comment: Thx Gary, I am using Junit 5.6.0, I tried `@SpringBootTest` but I end up with 
APPLICATION FAILED TO START

Field configProps in com.TopologyConfiguration required a bean of type 'com.ConfigureProps' that could not be found. 
basically TopologyConfiguration is my app class whose method is called in the test class. In the app class I am Autowiring the ConfigureProps but that comes up with the above error plus "Consider defining a bean of type 'com.xxx.ConfigureProps' in your configuration."

Comment: If you can post a complete, stripped down, app that exhibits this behavior, I can take a look to see what you are doing wrong. It's hard to guess with just snippets.

Comment: I added an example that works just fine for me.

Comment: just updated with proper code, can you please advise. 
Thank you

Comment: Just did that and ran a Test but I end up with 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find a `@SpringBootConfiguration`, you need to use `@ContextConfiguration` or `@SpringBootTest(classes=...)` with your test. I just have `@SpringBootTest` on my Test class. should I add `@SpringBootTest(classes=...)` if so what class name should go in this please.

Comment: Update: I had to add my main class name within SpringBootTest(classes) and now   the context loads fine.

Comment: I deleted my last comment; when I added `@ContextConfiguration(classes = { Config.class, MyProps.class })` the `MyProps.foo` is null; you need to include the class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` too. In my case `@ContextConfiguration(classes = { Config.class, MyProps.class, So67078244Application.class })` or `@SpringBootTest(classes = { Config.class, MyProps.class, So67078244Application.class })` works for me.

Comment: Gary, while I could load the properties, I had one last question, when I instantiate my application class in my test class. In this case TopologyConfiguration in my Test class, I get a NullPointer when getting properties using ConfigProps that is Autowired in my TopologyConfiguration class. This happens only when configProps obj is invoked within TopologyConfiguration, so am thinking the application context or something is not loaded full yet or only loaded ConfigProps in the context of test class?

Comment: I just autowired `MyProps` into my `Config` class above and it is fully populated, so I don't know what you are doing wrong.